# How to put a "," when another number is coming up, but not when there are anymore numbers to display C#

Tags: c#, primes

I'm trying to make a simple program on C#, that every time it finds a prime number it will display a `,` in between them, but not when there are no more prime numbers after that. It reads off from a file, which will display all the prime numbers from 1 till the number `X` given in a **.txt** file.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"(path to txt"))
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                int line = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
                int testsDone = 1;
                if (line == 1) Console.WriteLine("1");
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("1,");
                    while (testsDone <= line)
                    {
                        if (PrimeCheck(num) == true)
                        {
                            Console.Write("{0}", num);
                            if (testsDone < line) { Console.Write(","); }
                        }
                        //else Console.Write("( {0} ),", num); <-- testing
                        testsDone++;
                        num++;

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    num = onum;
                }
            }
    }

    private static bool PrimeCheck(int num)
    {
        if (num == 2 || num == 3 || num == 5) return true;
        else if (num % 2 != 0 && num % 3 != 0 && num % 5 != 0)
        {
            for (int div = 3; div < num; div += 2)
            {
                if (num % div == 0) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else if (num == 1) return false;
        else return false;
    }
```

Example .txt file:

```
10
5
```

Output I get:

> 2,3,5,7,
>
> 2,3,

Output I'm trying to get:

> 2,3,5,7
>
> 2,3

Comment: Start without the comma (1) then when you find a prime write  _Console.Write(",{0}", num);"_

Comment: this is very simple look into using the `string.Join(",", someList)` function create a list to hold the values else show single value... very simple

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone wants to see a [*Linqy*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) way

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var results = File.ReadLines(filename)
                  .Select(n => string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(2, int.Parse(n) - 2)
                                                          .Where(PrimeCheck)));

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `,` from the first write of `1` and then place it before every number you output after that:

```
Console.Write("1");
while (testsDone <= line) {
    if (PrimeCheck(num) == true) {        
        if (testsDone < line) { Console.Write(","); }
        Console.Write("{0}", num);
    }
    testsDone++;
    num++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to put the , before the output of each prime, eg.

```
Console.Write("1");

while (testsDone <= line)
{
    if (PrimeCheck(num) == true)
    {
       Console.Write(", {0}", num);
    }

    testsDone++;
    num++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have it add a comma only if it determines there are additional values to output instead of adding a comma just because you haven't reached the input value.

```
Console.Write("1");
while (testsDone <= line)
{
    if (PrimeCheck(num) == true)
    {
        Console.Write(", {0}", num);
    }
    testsDone++;
    num++;               
}
```

Comment: Just realized my edit is the same as David. Didn't even see there had been other answers after my vague one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could do if you convert that string of numbers to its own string variable.

```
string primeNumbers = "";
//add numbers to string
primeNumbers = primeNumbers.Substring(0, primeNumbers.Length - 1);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution to the problem, in pseudocode:

```
separator <- ", "

firstItem <- true;

for each item in itemList
  if (firstItem)
    firstItem <- false
  else
    print separator
  endif

  print item
end for
```

This prints the separator before every item on the list, except the first.